# Class extending JPanel doesn't update UI

Tags: java, swing

I have two classes: one which extends `JFrame` (`MyFrame`) and one which extends `JPanel` (`MyPanel`). The idea is to be able to add an instance of the `MyPanel` class to an existing, visible instance of `MyFrame`.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame () {
        setVisible(true);
        JPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        add(panel);
    }
}

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public MyPanel () {
        add(new JButton("Test"));
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    } 
}
```

The code runs and doesn't error, but the UI isn't updated when MyPanel is added to MyFrame.

Comment: Have you tried `repaint()` and `pack()` ?

Comment: Ah, `pack()` displays the JPanel elements successfully, but it screws up the layout quite significantly. Is there any other way of achieving this without affecting the current layout?

Comment: @user2696497 Change layout managers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like all the other questions relating to similar issues, move `setVisible(true);` to the end of the constructor.

Something like...

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame() {
        JPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        add(panel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Swing layouts are lazy, they won't update until you tell them to (or some other action, like the top level container been resized/reshown occurs)

You should also use `pack` to give your window a initial size, base on the size requirements of its content.

Having said all that, you really should avoid extending from top level containers like `JFrame`, lets face it, you're not really adding any new functionality to the class and instead, simply create a new instance when you need it...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new MyPanel());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've already tried adding `setVisible(true)`, no joy unfortunately.

Comment: @user2696497: no, don't *add* `setVisible(true)`, but instead ***move*** it, to the end of your MyFrame constructor. If this still doesn't work, edit your question with your latest non-functioning code.

Comment: @user2696497 And WHERE did you put it?  At the start of the constructor?  I suggested that you should put it at the END of the constructor

Comment: Ah I see. I should have expanded the code in my post more, because the panel isn't actually created/added in the constructor, but instead later on. Yes `setVisible(true)` is at the end of my constructor. I have now also added it after the code where the new instance of `MyPanel` is added and that's displayed the elements successfully.